# Download a PDF generated by Apps Script via web app

Tags: pdf, encoding, google-apps-script, character-encoding

I'm trying to figure out how to make a Google Apps Script deployed as a web app download a PDF that's generated on a click. It almost works, but the resulting file isn't valid. I can't figure out if it's an encoding issue or something else.

In Apps Script the code looks simple:

```
function makePDF() {
   ...
   var pdfBlob = doc.getAs('application/pdf');
   return Utilities.base64Encode(pdfBlob.getBytes());
}
```

In the browser, there's a click handler:

```
function clickHandler(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
    var pdf = new Blob([window.atob(data)]);
    var href = window.URL.createObjectURL(pdf);

    var link = document.querySelector('#hiddenLink');
    link.href = href;
    link.click();
  })
  .makePDF();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out, so posting the answer if anyone else is trying to pass a PDF from Apps Script to the client javascript. It's all much simpler than I had made it.

Rather than messing around with base64 encodings, just pass back the bytes array:

```
function makePDF() {
 ...
 var pdfBlob = DocumentApp.openById('1234').getAs('application/pdf');
 return pdfBlob.getBytes();
}
```

Now, on the client side, construct a new Blob from an ArrayBuffer. That's easy too:

```
function clickHandler(ev) {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
    var arr = new Uint8Array(data);
    var blob = new Blob([arr.buffer], {type: 'application/pdf'});

    var obj_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var hiddenLink = document.getElementById('hiddenPDFLink');
    hiddenLink.setAttribute('href', obj_url);
    hiddenLink.setAttribute('download', 'filename.pdf');
    hiddenLink.click();
  })
  .makePDF();
}
```

And that's it! Hope someone else finds this helpful.

Comment: I had the exact same situation, thanks for posting your solution

Comment: Hi! I've been trying to understand precisely the opposite, where a user would click on a button and this would send the "html page" to the server-side, so that it could be saved as pdf into a Google Drive Folder.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your makePDF function is doing some other stuffs/Calculation and at the end you need that document to be downloaded to local computer.

What you can do is inside success handler

```
var link = document.querySelector('#hiddenLink');
link.href = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=**TheIdOfDocumenToBeDownloaded**&exportFormat=pdf";
link.click();
```

It will then give you a prompt to save document on to local computer.

Comment: Thanks, that's a clean and simple solution, but there's an issue with authentication. My Apps Script is run as me but executable by everyone. It has access to Drive to read and write files, but I don't want those files to be readable by everyone, except via the Apps Script. I could try to change the permissions on the file in the script after it's been downloaded, but it would be nice not to have to worry about that.